# Sony ILX186K Linear CCD Datasheet

Tags: sensor, datasheet, ccd

I'm looking for the datasheet for a Sony ILX186K linear CCD sensor I've salvaged from a document scanner. This part was discontinued several years ago and the datasheet seems to be unavailable online through the usual means (extensive google searching). I've also contacted Sony Semicon however they claim to be unable to provide the datasheet due to the product's discontinued status.

Since the scanner I salvaged this sensor from (Epson Perfection 3490 Photo) is not functional, I'm not able to reverse-engineer the interface, however I'm expecting some of the pins to be a pixel clock and read-out gate, based on the information I've found for other sensors. I've traced out the schematic of the original circuit and identifed some of the pins (the analog outputs) but cannot discern with certainty which of the remaining pins are for the (suspected) clock and gate functions.

[image: Schematic]

Whilst I can probably figure it out by injecting some signals in the right places, it would be nice to have the datasheet before I move on. Does anyone have a copy of the datasheet for this sensor?

Comment: In 1998-1999 I've done a project involving a linear color CCD by Sony. I will search in my paperwork...

Comment: Did you look at the current image sensor datasheets? Maybe they have common pinout with the older versions.

Comment: @Naz Whilst I haven't checked exhaustively, I've not come across any so far that seems to match the schematic that I've drawn. Sony could not even recommend a part for equivalent replacement.